# Ruby MySQL backups using System() call with spaces

Tags: mysql, ruby

So I'm trying to create local daily backups of my MySQL database using a ruby script, but I'm not able to run this because there are issues in the mysql_dump_call string, when I call it in my script.

```
time = Time.new

puts "Current time: #{time.inspect}"

backup_path = "C:\\redmine_backups\\#{time.year}-#{time.month}-#{time.day}-time-#{time.hour}h-#{time.min}min-#{time.sec}sec\\"
backup_filename = "#{time.year}-#{time.month}-#{time.day}-redmine.sql"

system("mkdir #{backup_path}")

mysql_dump_executable = "C:\\Program Files\\MySQL\\MySQL Workbench 8.0 CE\\mysqldump.exe"

mysql_dump_call = "C:\\Program Files\\MySQL\\MySQL Workbench 8.0 CE\\mysqldump.exe --defaults-file=\"C:\\ProgramData\\MySQL\\MySQL Server 8.0\\my.conf\"
--user=root --host=localhost --protocol=tcp --port=3306 --default-character-set=utf8 --skip-triggers \"redmine\" > #{backup_path}"

if File.exist?(mysql_dump_executable)
    system('start', '', mysql_dump_call)
else
    puts "MySQLDump executable does not exist."
end
```

Anyone have any idea why it isn't working?
[image]

It looks like it's including my --defaults-file which is supposed to be a parameter. It works fine when I run this in powershell directly, or in command prompt.

Comment: Have you tried `system(mysql_dump_call)`? Does that work?

Answer (score 1):

You don't have a file with the name of the string stored in mysql_dump_call. Look at the documentation of the `system` function:

> system([env,] command... [,options]) → true, false or nil
>
> Executes command… in a subshell. command… is one of following forms.
>
> commandline          : command line string which is passed to the standard shell

> cmdname, arg1, ...   : command name and one or more arguments (no shell)

> [cmdname, argv0], arg1, ... : command name, argv[0] and zero or more arguments

From what I know, the `start` command wants to see the program to start and the arguments as individual parameters. Hence I would try something like:

```
 system('start', mysql_dump_executable, '--defaults-file=\"C:\\ProgramData\\MySQL\\MySQL Server 8.0\\my.conf\"', ....)
```

Or use the command line form:

```
system("start #{mysql_dump_call}")
```

Comment: so the good news is i have it working now but i can't use > myfile.sql in a system() call. How can I get the resulting data into a file?

Comment: If you use the "commandline" form, the string should be passed to the command processor (in your case probably cmd.exe), and this should set up the redirection. In case this does not work, ask a new question here at SO. An alternative would be to run the commandline as `output = %x(COMMANDLINE)`, which stores the resulting data into your Ruby variable, from where you can store it into any file you like.

Comment: @RyanGlen You could switch to `Open3` and handle the file writing yourself, that would avoid the shell and its quoting issues completely. Also, AFAIK Windows is usually happy with Unix-style paths (i.e. `C:/ProgramData/MySQL/MySQL Server 8.0/my.conf`) so that might help with the escaping as well.

Comment: @muistooshort : Most system functions from Windows allow `/` as path separator, but if you run the cmd-shell or (AFIK) the Power Shell, this is not possible. For unfortunate historic reason, `/` is used to indicate command line options (similar to `-` in Unix) and therfore `cmd` can not understand if i.e. `DIR /X` is supposed to mean the directory `\X` or a command line switch `/X`. Hence only `\` for pathes when they are interpreted by the Windows command shell.

Comment: Yeah, we're stuck with CPM forever it seems. But if we go with `Open3` instead of `system`, then we can get redirection (or at least do it by hand) without having to worry about the shell. Been awhile since I've had to use Windows without a cygwin or similar to protect me :)